# Injection of a backspace key into query text?

Tags: c, network-programming

I recently bought a book on C that works around the idea of network protocols and how to code around items such as cookies and sending packets to a server when I thought of something. Could you inject a backspace into a query? I know that at first sounds a little bit stupid but here is my logic on this. If you monitor outbound packets when you go to a website you can find the way a query is stated, using this you could recreate that packet but change the text sent to the server to contain a character that is assigned to the value of 08 (backspace)

I ask wondering if it may be possible as you ca send data over a network through C and look at the hex value of it and notice that a backspace character doesn't delete the previous character until the string gets formatted at destination. I am curious as to whether this could be a method of implementing a SQL injection because if you format it in a way so that you delete something that gets escaped after it is escaped during the string formatting process then you could escape the next backslash (used to escape a character) which would allow you to do your attack with little to no difficulty.

So if you want visualization of what the string might look like when sent to the query and after then i will make an attempt.

string_before_format = ['][bs]['][sql injection]
during format = [][]['][sql injection]

I might be wrong with how I am thinking about this to which I would be happy, otherwise I think it would be curious to see if this could be possible. Before they are mentioned I would also say that the reason that I don't go out and try this is due to the fact that attempting to do a SQL injection is more of a grey area that network admins may not appreciate and I would rather not go to jail, and that I myself have no experience setting up and hosting a server so if I made one myself then I would have no guarantee that it is held to community standards of safety meaning that I may have implemented things differently that allowed such an attack to be possible.

Comment: In my experience, no. I too had this thought about three or four years ago, so I went ahead and tried it. It did not work for me at that time in the environment I was testing. `0x08` has no special meaning until it is entered as a keystroke, but until then, it is just a meaningless, undisplayable character. Maybe if there was some weird coding where the payload/query was being fed through STDIN to something, this idea could work, but even then, I would not bet on it. Nonetheless, that is based on my personal experience, so perhaps someone else can offer more insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send ASCII code 8 (backspace) in network messages, but it's not very likely to do anything interesting because backspace is just one of many unprintable characters.  It only has the special meaning of "move the cursor backward" in a terminal or terminal emulator.  It's not likely that a program meant to receive whole query strings would implement any special logic for backspace as opposed to many other nonprintable characters.

Of course if you want to be sure you have to try it (on a system that belongs to you!).